# MATLAB: Plotting Time on Xaxis - overlapping label

Tags: matlab, plot

I am having difficulties on plotting time on the xaxis. I have some overlapping labels. See below:

[image: plot]

This is my code:

```
time=datenum(0,0,0,0,0,timeinseconds);
labs=1:10:length(time);

figure(3);
plotyy(time,xvalue,time,dens);
datetick('x','HH:MM');
set(gca,'XTick',time(labs),'XTickLabel',time(labs)); 
legend('xval','CDF');
title('Crash on Oct.10 2008 at 15:59pm');
xlabel('Time');
```

First, why are the labels overlapping with the old ones? And secondly, how I can get the label to rotate 90degrees? I tried some other matlab functions to turn the labels but none seem able to tackle time format labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `plotyy` you create two `axis` objects. Your overlap problem does probably come from the fact that you modify only one set of those axis, while leaving the other as it was originally set up.

One option is handling both of the created axis when you call `plotyy` by:

```
[AX, H1, H2] = plotyy( time, xvalue, time, dens);
```

Your first option here is setting up both of the axis, contained within the array of handlers `AX`, via changing the`'XTick'` propriety as:

```
set( AX(1), 'XTick', time(labs), 'XTickLabel', time(labs));
set( AX(2), 'XTick', time(labs), 'XTickLabel', time(labs));
```

But you also have the option of leaving the labels for the second axis empty, replacing the second line above:

```
set( AX(1), 'XTick', time(labs), 'XTickLabel', time(labs));
set( AX(2), 'XTick', time(labs), 'XTickLabel', []);
```

The official documentation of [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) and [Using Multiple X- and Y-Axes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f1-11215.html) can be of further help for you.

---

If you take a look on the example there, namely, [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) documentation:

```
figure
x = 0:0.01:20;
y1 = 200*exp(-0.05*x).*sin(x);
y2 = 0.8*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2,'plot');
```

and as you did before, try to modify only the `AX(2)`, which is equivalent to what you got writing `gca`:

```
set(AX(2),'XtickLabel',1:0.1:20)
```

you will observe that the same overlapping error takes place.

With respect to rotating the labels 90 deg, I'm afraid that's not currently supported by Matlab. However, you can probably get that done using one of the available packages on FileExchange. Either [xticklabelrotate](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabelrotate) or [Rotate Tick Label](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722) could be the one.

Comment: thanks for the help! but when I implement your suggestions ` I get an error `"Error using set. Value must be numeric"`

Comment: I believe that `datetick('x','HH:MM');` might be the problem

Comment: I updated completing the example. Your error may be on one of your variables: `xvalue`, `time`, `dens`or `labs`. But if you suspect of `datetick` try using it as `datetick(AX(1),'x','HH:MM')` to modify the first axis `x` labels

Comment: Bingo! I solved the code like follow: `[AX, H1, H2] = plotyy( time, xvalue, time, dens);
set( AX(1), 'XTick', time(labs), 'XTickLabel', time(labs));
set( AX(2), 'XTick', time(labs), 'XTickLabel', time(labs)); datetick(AX(1),'x','HH:MM');datetick(AX(2),'x','HH:MM');`

Comment: Good. Well that's basically like what I showed on the second snippet, so you are keeping both of the `XTickLabel` filled with the same data and superimposing one on the top of the other. Glad it helped